# Get state of toggled element

Tags: javascript, toggle, angular-ui

I am building an application with angularui. I have a a span that contains an image that I need to toggle on and off and save the state on when user hits save. How do I get the toggle state of this element?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="scrollable" ng-controller="UpdateProspectCtrl">
<div class="scrollable-content section">
    <form role="form" ng-submit='updateProspect()'>
        <fieldset>
            <p ui-state="pinProspect" ng-model="pinprospectpara"
               ui-class="{'text-primary': pinProspect}"
               class="text-default">

                <span ng-model="pinprospect" style="font-size: 40px; display: block;"
                   class="fa fa-paperclip" ui-toggle='pinProspect'
                   ui-class="{'active': pinProspect}" ng-click="setPinned()"></span>
            </p>
        </fieldset><hr>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Save
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('Main', [
      'mobile-angular-ui.core.sharedState'])
    .controller('UpdateProspectCtrl', function($scope){
      // set the state here on click of the toggelable span.
      $scope.setPinned = function() {
        $scope.updateProspectPinned = !$scope.updateProspectPinned;
        console.log("setting pinned to", $scope.updateProspectPinned);
      };

      // Using the above function I am able to guage the state. However, next time when I load this page I want to set the last state. If the user had selected it, I want to show it as selected. How do I achieve this behavior?
    })
```

Also, even though I have given it an ng-model I am unable to access it in my controller. I can access all the remaining elements of the page except for this span and its container p tags. What could be the issue?

Comment: can you post more of your code? also the angular controller?

Comment: @messerbill: I have updated the question with more detailed code html as well as controller.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt bind ng-model directive to anything else but inputs and textareas, it is not meant for a span, if you want to display  the model use - 
 {{updateProspectPin}}

The ng-click directive should be the one responsible for toggling the value.

If you want to save the state you should open an angular service which is a singleton, and store the saved state there.

New service -

```
function pinnedStateService (localStorageService) {
    var service = this;

    service.pinState = { value: getPinStateFromLocalStorage()}; 

    service.toggleState = function () {
      service.pinState.value = !service.pinState.value;
      localStorageService.set("pinItem", this.pinState.value);// i am not sure this is the correct syntax
    }

    function getPinStateFromLocalStorage() {
        return localStorageService.get("pinItem"); // i am not sure this is the correct syntax
    }
}

function controller(pinnedStateService){
  $scope.pinState = pinnedStateService.pinState;
  $scope.toggleState = pinnedStateService.toggleState; // binding function to scope so you can use it on the view
}
```

in the view -

```
 <element ui-class="{'active': pinState}" />
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I am able to save the state, but how do I set the state in the UI element again? Say for example if I set the state to selected, I can save it but next time I load the page I want to show the image already selected. How do I achieve that?

Comment: You mean a full page reload ? If so you save this value either to a database or browsers  localstorage/cookies

Comment: you can use this plugin for angular integration with the browser's localStorage to save any information you want, in your case the pinnedState, it will stay as long the user erases its browser temp data,            https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: I think I am not able to explain myself properly here. I am able to save the state in the localStorage. However, when I reload this current page I want to set the UI element enabled. That is what I am unable to achieve. I use ui-class="{'active': pinProspect}" to set the pinned to status to active or inactive. However, I am unable to access $scope.pinProspect. I want to set this variable to true in order to show the UI element already selected. How do I achieve this?

Comment: i edited the code, take a look again i think it should work fine for you. let me know